# UILocalNotification keeps pushes multiple messages

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have a `Struct ArrayBook` that holds an **Array** and a function called `randomList` which returns the **Array** and passes a random number through e.g. `return arrayList[randomNumber]`. So basically when I call `ArrayBook.randomList` it will return a random item from the array everytime it is executed - I have tested this in playgrounds and with Xcode with Unbutton function.

Now that is clear, I have a functioning `UILocalNotification` that schedules a local push notification hourly (for testing) with the message being `ArrayBook.randomList`. But when receiving the notification the application pushes multiple messages at once which increase by 1 every hour. I cannot figure out why this is, any ideas ?

```
    var dateComp:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComp.year = 2015;
    dateComp.month = 06;
    dateComp.day = 03;
    dateComp.hour = 01;
    dateComp.minute = 00;
    dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    var calender:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    var date:NSDate = calender.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!

    var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.category = "Daily"
    notification.alertBody = arrayBook.randomList()
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not running that code multiple times (maybe you schedule a new Notification every time you open one?)

Comment: @VWGolf2 No there are not multiple copies of the code.. but I had once tried out the code for every 30second which lead to notifications still being pushed regularly after changing the repeatInterval to hourly. But now they are sent out hourly but multiple messages :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are calling the code to schedule the notification repeatedly - you have to otherwise you will always get the same `alertBody` since it is set when the notification is scheduled, not when the notification is delivered.

Since you specify `notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour` this notification will be delivered every hour along with all of the other notifications you have scheduled - increasing by one each time.  You should remove the `repeatInterval` from your notification.

Comment: If I remove 'repeatInterval' then I won't have a scheduled notification. I am trying to schedule a daily notification to send a random string from an array. How could I check all scheduled notifications.

Comment: If you remove `repeatInterval` you will have a scheduled notification, it just won't repeat automatically.  Repeating won't really help you though because it will just show you the same notification each time.  You need to schedule a series of notifications, each with a different random string and a day apart. There is a limit of 20 notifications that can be scheduled at once, so each time your app is launched you can retrieve the list of scheduled notifications then schedule some more.

Comment: I have the ' UILocalNotification ' code above within my ' viewDidLoad ' container. This might be pushing a new notification every time the app is opened which is delivered hourly along with other notifications. I don't want to manually schedule every day of the month then keep pushing updated for the app for new schedules.

Comment: That is what you have to do. As I keep saying, even if you scheduled a repeating notification you would just get the same text every time because the body is set when you submit the notification, not when the notification is displayed

Comment: After further testing I not only is the same notification repeated, but another is scheduled at the same time every time the app is loaded with a new random message. I could have a generic message repeated every morning to visit the app but now I have found it is duplicating after every open

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to show where you are calling the scheduling code from, but you must be calling it each time the app launches.

Comment: I called it in the view did load :/ where is the best place to call it ?

Comment: I would probably do it in `didFinishLaunching` in the App Delegate - wherever you do it you need to think through your strategy - do you want a single, repeating, notification that just prompts the user to open the app or do you want to schedule multiple non-repeating notifications with different messages.  Either way you need to determine what notification(s) have already been scheduled and take the appropriate action